# How to avoid parent widget warning when using QFileDialog class?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyside

I'm studying Python and PyQt5 in Microsoft Windows 7. My IDE is PyCharm 4.5 CE.

I am trying to make the file dialog to users can select the files or directories easily.

My code is...

```
# coding: utf-8

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QFileDialog


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_gui()

    def init_gui(self):

        file_names = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "Select one or more files to open", "C:/Windows", "")
        print(file_names)

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 300)
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code works properly. But the only thing that annoying me is this.
[image]

There are many buttons in parent main window and one of the button shows file dialog.

What is the proper parent in this situation?

Comment: Your code is correct. PyCharm is just getting it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `PyQt5` documentation the method signature is:

```
QStringList getOpenFileNames (QWidget parent=None, QString caption=QString(), QString directory=QString(), QString filter=QString(), QString selectedFilter=None, Options options=0)
```

The parent must be an instance of `QWidget` or of some class that inherits from `QWidget`, and that's exactly what `QMainWindow` is (and this explains why everything works as expected).

Now, to understand why PyCharm displays a warning: if you look in the `QFileDialog.py` file, which is automatically generated by PyCharm from `PyQt5\QtWidgets.pyd` you will see that the method `getOpenFileNames` is not declared as `staticmethod` nor as `classmethod`:

```
def getOpenFileNames(self, QWidget_parent=None, str_caption='', str_directory='', str_filter='', str_initialFilter='', QFileDialog_Options_options=0): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
    """ QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(QWidget parent=None, str caption='', str directory='', str filter='', str initialFilter='', QFileDialog.Options options=0) -> (list-of-str, str) """
    pass
```

so PyCharm expects (wrongly) the method to be called on an instance of `QFileDialog`, but here you have no instance of `QFileDialog` (as the method docstring suggests the real method signature is unknown), hence it expects the first argument of the method (`self`) to be an instance of `QFileDialog` and thus it throws a warning.

You can turn off such warning by disabling the inspection just for the desired statement:

```
# noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyCallByClass
file_names = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "Select one or more files to open", "C:/Windows", "")
print(file_names)
```

Comment: A lot of what you say here is wrong. The comment after the method definition says it all: `# real signature unknown; restored from __doc__`. So the signature is clearly wrong. The method most certainly **is** static in both Qt and PyQt, and for a good reason. The `QFileDialog` constructor can only create an instance of Qt's built-in file-dialog, whereas the static methods use the platform's native file-dialog. So passing in an instance of `QFileDialog` is not the right thing to do. The OPs code is right; PyCharm is wrong.

Comment: You are saying exactly what I wanted to point out in my post. Obviously the method is static in PyQt else it won't work, but if you inspect the declaration of the method from within PyCharm you won't see it declared as static, so PyCharm expects the first argument to be an instance of QFileDialog, and then displays (wongly) the warning. I didn't say that PyQt is wrong, but that PyCharm inspection is.

Comment: Okay. I was mainly questioning the part that begins "When you call `QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames`...", which quite strongly suggests invoking the method as an instance method, but doesn't state that this is actually the *wrong* thing to do. (PS: you also say "look in PyQt5 source" - but I'm not quite sure what you're referring to there).

Comment: With "look in PyQt5 source" I meant the method signature I added right below.

Comment: Sorry - I meant: where did you get that from (what source code, and in which files, etc).

Comment: From within PyCharm, right click on the method name -> Goto -> Declaration will open `QFileDialog.py` generated automatically from from `PyQt5\QtWidgets.pyd`. There figures the method signature that PyCharm uses for the inspection.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking you literally meant the PyQt5 sources (which obviously makes no sense). I have never used PyCharm. Presumably, these are stub files that PyCharm auto-generates for third-party extensions.

Comment: Yes, those are files automatically generated by the PyCharm indexer and are used for things like method auto completion, syntax inspection etc. Apparently PyCharm is not able to recover the correct method signature (probably it's not even possible unless JetBrains guys manually teach the IDE) and thus it throws warnings (and that's not the only case where PyCharm fails when inspecting PyQt application).

Comment: I edited my post. Hopefully I made more clear that the problem is within PyCharm.

Comment: It seems that pycharm already has support for [type hinting](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), and sip/pyqt will also support it eventually (not quite sure what the current status of that is). Anyway, it looks like things may improve in the near future.

Comment: @DanielePantaleone
Thank you "Daniele"! You've taught me really great things more than I expected. You look like the light of hope to me. :-) And thank you too, "ekhumoro". You're a good advisor!